# lxml add literal string

Tags: python, lxml

Is it possible to insert a literal string using the `Element.addprevious` or `Element.addnext` methods?

I want to convert:

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

to

```html
string
<div>Content</div>
```

I tried using `lxml.objectify.StringElement`, but it will add a `<StringElement>` tag.

Is it possible to insert a literal string anywhere in the DOM using lxml, or every element must have tag, because it could break lxml tree?

Comment: The string could be added as the `text` of the parent element or as the `tail` of a preceding sibling element.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = '''
<div>Content</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml) # Instantiate a doc
div = doc.div # Get the element
div.insertBefore('string\n')
print(doc.html)
```

Result:

```
string
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to do that with pure lxml. I used beautiful soup finally to achieve this, using `insert_before` method

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to implement this with pure lxml.